# Half red circle with active green dots for every slide of the slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, progress-bar

I'm building vertical slider with active dots and everything is okey until I came to the style of my [final idea image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPd1h.png) . I have this halved red line with the green dot inside. I would like to represent the default dots from my slider like the attached picture, so when you move one slide the green dot also moves UP and DOWN only INSIDE the red halved line. I need ideas how I can build this halved red line with the green dots inside and each dot will correspond to my current active slide. I do not want you guys to build it for me!!! I just do not have any ideas how it can be done with css and html. I appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Please look css conic-gradient.

Comment: I think i would do it with an svg. Each of the "dots: could have it's own id, or class, or data-attribute, so you could then target it with your JS / CSS and add the "active" state to the correct "dot"

Comment: Put the dot at the top of a long thin div which you then rotate the required amount. The red bit you could draw with conic and radial gradients.